# Atributo da classe não gera erro ao ser comentado

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tive uma dúvida que não consegui resolver. Seguem os códigos de 3 arquivos

Usuario.php

```
class Usuario{
    //protected $nome;

    public function getNome() {
        return $this->nome;
    }

    public function setNome($nome){
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }
}
```

Aluno.php

```
class Aluno extends Usuario{

}
```

index.php

```
$aluno = new Aluno();

$aluno->setNome($_POST['nome']);          

echo $aluno->getNome();
```

Como pode se ver, o atributo $nome está comentado e a linha `$aluno->setNome($_POST['nome']);` me retorna o valor do campo preenchido no formulário. Eu achei isso estranho, porque pensei que tinha que vir uma mensagem de variável indefinida, ou algo do tipo.

A minha dúvida que ficou foi a seguinte, como o nome do aluno imprime na tela normalmente se o atributo `$nome` está comentado?

As conexões e outras coisas mais estão certinhas, só não coloquei tudo para não ficar muito grande.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é devido ao PHP permitir que ser crie membros de classe dinamicamente em tempo de execução, onde você pode evitar isso utilizando o método mágico **__set**, como no exemplo a seguir:

```
<?php

class Usuario
{
  //protected $nome;

  public function getNome()
  {
    return $this->nome;
  }

  public function setNome($nome)
  {
    $this->nome = $nome;
  }

  public function __set($name, $value)
  {}

}
```

**__set**: Esse método mágico é executado todo vez que ser tenta definir dados a um membro indefinido em uma classe.

Comment: Não resolve o problema de escopo, caso a variável não tenha sido previamente inicializada.

Answer (score 4):

Não acho que alguém consiga explicar porque os *designers* da linguagem escolheram fazer isto, além deles próprios, mas sei que eles resolveram que se você se referenciar a um membro que não existe este deve ser criado automaticamente de forma pública.

Isto é algo terrível que uma linguagem pode fazer, escondendo erros. Muitas pessoas dirão que este é um dos motivos do PHP ser ruim e nem tem a desculpa do JavaScript que cometeu os erros no começo por ter sido criada em 2 meses. São erros cometidos ao longo do processo em mais de 20 anos.

Se deseja essa segurança então deve escolher outra linguagem.

Veja como [o membro realmente é criado](http://ideone.com/qahdik).

[Não gosto do termo atributo, prefiro campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Answer (score 2):

Como já foi antes dito, o PHP cria membros dinamicamente, se este não existir e for chamado, é simplesmente criado, mas se já existir, retorna o valor dessa propriedade. Quando se usa classes, caso a propriedade não tenha sido previamente *"inicializada"*, ela é automaticamente criada como public.

> Class properties must be defined as public, private, or protected. If declare using var, the property will be defined as public.

Abaixo um exemplo:

```
<?php

class AlunoA
{

    protected $aluno;

    public function getNome(){
        return $this->aluno;
    }
    public function setNome($nome){
        $this->aluno = $nome;
    }

}
class AlunoB
{

    //public $aluno; # comentado ou não é o mesmo nessa situação

    public function getNome(){
        return $this->aluno;
    }
    public function setNome($nome){
        $this->aluno = $nome;
    }

}

$alunoA = new AlunoA();
$alunoB = new AlunoB();
var_dump($alunoA); # object(AlunoA)#1 (1) { ["aluno":protected]=> NULL } 
print "<br/>";
var_dump($alunoB); # object(AlunoB)#2 (0) { } 

?>
```

Para a classe `AlunoB`, a propriedade aluno torna-se visível, dentro e fora da classe, ou seja, pode-se acessar essa propriedade através do `$this`, ou através de uma instância pode-se ler/mudar o valor de `$aluno`, ou ler directamente o seu valor, o que não garante que se mantenha a integridade desse objecto.

```
$alunoA = new AlunoA();
$alunoB = new AlunoB();
var_dump($alunoA); # object(AlunoA)#1 (1) { ["aluno":protected]=> NULL } 
print "<br/>";
$alunoB->aluno = 'Edilson'; 
var_dump($alunoB); # object(AlunoB)#2 (1) { ["aluno"]=> string(7) "Edilson" }
```

Podes obter mais detalhes [aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).