# Qual a diferença entre atributo e campo, nas classes?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, terminologia, propriedade, atributos, campos

Quando estou estudando programação orientada a objetos, em alguns momentos ouço falar de campos e atributos de uma classe, porém os dois parecem ser definições diferentes para se referir a mesma coisa. Qual a diferença?

Aproveitando, podemos dizer que uma propriedade é um atributo ou um campo?

Comment: Você não tem ideia o quanto eu esperei por esta pergunta.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Assunto bastante controverso, mas não deveria. Todo mundo pode ter sua opinião, pode seguir uma escola específica, mas tem evidências que a maior parte do uso é o que coloco aqui. Não renego que seja usado de outras formas, as cito.

## [Atributo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96710/101)

É uma característica em específico que um objeto terá, mas não se define bem como esta característica será disponível no objeto. Não importa se será um campo, uma propriedade, um método, ou outra coisa, ou até um conjunto desses mecanismos.

O termo costuma ser usado mais abstratamente, no projeto da aplicação no geral e não na programação. Há muitas pessoas que usam na programação como se fosse um campo, o que eu penso ser equivocado, ainda que cause pouco mal.

Algumas vezes ele é usado como se fosse uma propriedade, e aí até está mais ou menos correto. Veja a definição de propriedade mais abaixo.

Um atributo é um conjunto de regras, é como deve ser, comportar-se, algo que é próprio daquele tipo de objeto.

Então uma definição possível seria que ele é um conjunto de estado, opcional, e comportamentos, opcionais, que tem um foco para atender uma especificidade daquele objeto, para determinar uma característica que aquele objeto terá. Não que seja a única forma de ver o conceito, mas é aceitável em algum contexto.

Esse [artigo do Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/apsupp/properties.pdf) trabalha com esta definição. Não formalmente, o artigo é um pouco vago, minha interpretação foi essa.

O estado pode eventualmente definir tipo, formato, valor padrão, outras características restritivas. Desconheço algum mecanismo que guarde estado em um código que seja diferente de [variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) ou constantes ([no sentido de apenas leitura depois de inicializado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151721/101)).

#### Do que ele é composto

Os comportamentos costumam ser métodos, mas há outras formas de especificar comportamento em algumas linguagens, ainda que no fundo acabe sendo indiretamente algo muito [parecido com uma função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212265/101).

Com frequência o atributo só tem um campo em sua definição, daí vem a ideia que são a mesma coisa. Atributo é conceitual, ponto! Se ele está em um nível diferente dos outros termos, como a propriedade, como poderia ser a mesma coisa?

Acredito que ele possa ser usado como **nome do campo**, que é diferente de ser o campo. Por exemplo: "razão social" é o nome de campo que guarda o nome de pessoas jurídicas, então "razão social" é um atributo de um campo que tem essa característica. Isto encaixa na ideia de ser uma informação acessória, descritiva, modificativa, e não a informação principal do objeto, não o valor.

A definição da resposta do utluiz me parece ir um pouco nessa linha, embora mais colateralmente, já que a definição do campo indica isso, a de atributo indica outra coisa em contexto específico, o que discordo porque ela ignora tudo o que foi dito aqui que é confuso usar o mesmo termo para mais de um conceito ou mecanismo, ou que já existem outros mecanismos usando o termo atributo. Me parece uma visão de do tipo "todo mundo diz isso então vou aceitar que seja isso, mesmo que tenha falhas na definição". E obviamente discordo da conclusão que seja artificial, a não ser que tudo acabe sendo considerado artificial. Concordo apenas com o fato de haver aplicação em contexto específico. E esta resposta é toda sobre resolver o conflito quando os contextos interseccionam e os termos criam confusão. Por isso a distinção não é irrelevante, e mostra como OOP trouxe mais confusão que solução.

#### As linguagens usam para um mecanismo específico.

É comum as linguagens **não** citarem atributo como mecanismo delas ([procure aí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/information/glossary.html)), ou então [o termo ser usado para outro mecanismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/101) diferente do falado aqui, embora eu ache que o termo só deveria ser usado para isto.

[C++ também usa o termo para modificadores que qualificam uma parte do código](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes), e não para definir um membro de um tipo. [C também](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html).

[Em Java costumam usar o termo para as partes da anotação](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1805200/221800), que também é um qualificador, ou seja, funciona como no HTML.

[Python também](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/), embora use com um complemento para desambiguar.

[Na comunidade PHP](https://github.com/doctrine/annotations/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/Annotation/Attribute.php) parece que está indo pelo mesmo caminho.

Tem até um [paradigma sobre atributo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute-oriented_programming).

Note que existem atributos que fazem parte da linguagem. `static`, `private`, `readonly`, `virtual`, `async`, `abstract`, `final`, todas essas coisas são atributos.

#### UML

Em [UML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) é comum usar o termo. Mas muitas vezes usam campo também. Não vi propriedade onde pesquisei, pelo menos para isto.

Não achei na especificação qual é o termo correto, quando usar um ou outro, ou mesmo se está certo usar ambos.

Eu acho estranho uma linguagem de modelagem se envolver com detalhe de implementação, e se for assim, considero ela desnecessária. Na prática muitas pessoas consideram, já que seu uso é bem restrito entre os programadores (mesmo que tenha muitos milhares deles usando, ainda é longe do total de milhões), e minha opinião é que a maioria que usa estão sem ganhos reais. Não é só minha opinião, [tem dados](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/uml-designers-have-been-removed-layer-designer-now-supports-live-architectural-analysis/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Eu achava que UML era sobre formalismos. Se uma definição mais ou menos serve não vejo porque usar UML ou ferramentas parecidas.

Já parou pra pensar que a formalização da UML está errada? Pode acontecer, tem inúmeros casos que isto ocorreu. As pessoas não contestam.

Uma ferramenta criada para unificar a comunicação em um projeto que diz o **oposto** do que as pessoas usam nas linguagens é algo fundamentalmente quebrada. Mas todo mundo pode ter a opinião que quiser, inclusive que todas as linguagens que são assim é que estão erradas.

Curiosamente UML é defendida por adotantes de Agile. Não entendo isso.

#### Definição fraca

O termo é [considerado por muitos como vago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10115625/221800), ambíguo (veja logo abaixo da citação do dicionário em amarelo a seguir) e controverso (em cada lugar tem uma definição diferente), então não deveria ser aplicado formalmente, e não deveria ser tomado como verdade absoluta, como também muitos o fazem.

Algumas fontes consolidaram a ideia de que ambos são a mesma coisa e algumas pessoas acham que isto não pode ser contestado. Mas há fontes mostrando o contrário.

É mais ou menos como [*duck typing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/574146/101). Um termo que, ou não quer dizer nada, ou diz algo que já existia e não precisava dele.

#### Outras formas de ver

- Achei uma "escola" que usa o termo para indicar uma característica associada a uma classe ou membro dela, eventualmente até em outras coisas. De fato é a definição usada na [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_(computing)), e como o termo é efetivamente [usado em muitas situações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/101). E [usado em diversos lugares](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/define-modify-work-item-fields?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

  Então campo seria um substantivo, método um verbo (sua ação em si não deixa de ser um substantivo), assim como classes não deixam de ser substantivos em certo contexto, e atributo seria um adjetivo que sempre é aplicado a substantivos).

  Isto estando correto, e acho que está, [minha resposta que gerou alguma polêmica está correta não só no contexto do .NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/101).

  Há até um [paradigma que prega o seu uso desta forma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute-oriented_programming).

  UML prefere chamar de [estereótipo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype_(UML)) (mais uma vez, diferente de tudo o que as pessoas usam efetivamente).
- Vi que em [alguns lugares](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323861.aspx) é usado de forma exatamente oposta. Um atributo seria como um campo (substantivo), e ele teria propriedades (adjetivo). Achei horrível. Mas é questão de ponto de vista. Pra mim atributo implica ser um adjetivo, um substantivo só poderia ser a concretude para aplicar a qualidade.

  > a·tri·bu·to substantivo masculino
  >
  > 1. Qualidade própria e inerente.
  > 2. Faculdade.
  > 3. Sinal distintivo.
  > 4. [Gramática]  .Adjetivo (ou locução .adjetiva) que qualifica um nome.
  > 5. Nome predicativo.
  >
  > "atributo", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
  > 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/atributo [consultado em
  > 14-01-2018].
- Em vários contextos da computação atributo é um metadado (adjetivo) e não o dado ([arquivo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_attribute), [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_attribute) e outras linguagens de marcação, [análise de linguagem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_grammar), além da já citada acima usada como anotação).

  Me parece mais algo definindo um estilo, um jeito, mas não uma parte de um objeto. Note que o uso do termo como se fosse um campo é exatamente uma parte do objeto, é muito concreto.
- É verdade que há [uso como uma coluna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_(database)) de um objeto maior. Acho que foi um erro que se perpetuou em OOP.

  Como se chama as características de uma coluna? Parece que isto não foi definido. Talvez chamem de propriedade :P. E talvez explique porque algumas escolas vão por este caminho. Chega ser irônico, porque é comum os proponentes de OO rejeitarem em algum grau a álgebra relacional.

  Acredito que na época enxergavam o atributo como não podendo ser outra coisa a não ser uma coluna (campo), e ficou uma definição ruim. Ou não, pode ser que definiram certo e os seguidores não entenderam que o atributo era conceitual, e a implementação concreta precisaria de algo concreto, como a coluna física (campo) ou virtual (propriedade), vai saber.

  Ou está certo e por isto as linguagens é que estariam erradas, o que seria um infortúnio.

  Quem achar algo, eu gostaria de saber.

  Por que não usamos o termo coluna então? Mais um infortúnio. As implementações do modelo relacional chama, e acho ela mais importante que o conceito teórico.
- A [ciência define como uma característica de um objeto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_and_attribute_(research)) e não uma parte dele.

  Diz inclusive que uma variável é um conjunto de atributos. Nós desenvolvedores criamos um campo com nome vinculado a uma posição de memória (variável), com um domínio (tipo), [tempo de vida, escopo e visibilidade definidos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101), um valor padrão, forma de inicialização, capacidade de mutação, alinhamento, forma e local de alocação, restrições, *labels* e *tags*, e outros penduricalhos úteis (nem todas linguagens permitem tudo isto sintaticamente e precisam ser emuladas com métodos e disciplina manual).

  Por outro lado, no mesmo verbete dá a entender que o atributo é a definição inicial proposta aqui, que seria uma informação específica. Como ela é obtida não importa, então faria mais sentido confundir atributo com propriedade do que com campo.

  Nos dois casos campo não pode ser confundido com atributo.
- Também diz-se que é uma informação acessória que leva ao entendimento de que é um metadado, algo que [modifica uma característica de um objeto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_modifier), em contraposição a ser uma parte de um objeto.
- Em [ontologia fala-se em características](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_components), deixa em aberto o que [pode ser uma parte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_components#Attributes), o que vem ao encontro do que está definido desde o início desta resposta. Ela pode ser uma parte apenas por circunstância, se for o que define uma qualidade do objeto.
- Aparentemente [Ruby trata como o valor adjetivado](https://www.thoughtco.com/using-attributes-2908103) de em campo (variável de instância). Posso aceitar esta definição. O artigo não foi proposto por mim, peguei de outra [resposta controversa sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75397/101).

  E entendo que DDD (Domain Design Driven) do Eric Evans diz o mesmo, conforme mostra a mesma resposta. Lá não fala nada que atributo é um campo ou propriedade. Lá indica ser um valor, inclusive porque ninguém muda campo, muda o valor do campo, é possível interpretar atributo como seu o valor do campo, ainda que não goste desta definição. Mas dá margem a entender que é apenas a característica que o valor pode ter, o que, nesta hipótese, remeteria ser apenas uma anotação do campo ou propriedade.

  Curiosamente nesse trecho a resposta renega o que foi dito na seção anterior informando que um atributo não é um campo.

  O mesmo vale para o livro da GoF sobre *design patterns*. É possível interpretar que estão falando da mesma coisa, mas também podem estar falando de outra coisa. Não está explícito, então não é evidência que os termos são intercambiáveis.

  Na seção seguinte faz-se afirmações que não tem nada que comprove e em que contexto foram usadas. E a seção termina com uma clara informação falsa, conforme minha resposta lá mostra.

  E a última citação de libro na seção ocorre o mesmo, diz que é evidência algo que não costa na citação.

  Concordo com a conclusão (ainda que tenha alguns detalhes falsos menos relevantes), ainda que ela não responda a pergunta lá, seria boa aqui. Lá fala-se do mecanismo específico. Aqui fala-se do nível conceitual. A conclusão fala que os termos são iguais, mas mostra que são diferentes quando diz que a propriedade é o mecanismo de implementação do atributo. Toda a discussão lá (já apagada) era sobre usar a terminologia correta, o que não foi feito.

Então hora fala-se do conceito geral que adjetiva o objeto hora do mecanismo de modificar algo em um substantivo. Nunca do campo em si, se concluir que onde pode estar falando também pode ser uma interpretação errada.

Você só deveria usar o termo atributo quando está em um nível de abstração acima, jamais quando está falando de variáveis de tipos no código.

Se uma série de ferramentas e literatura definem termos errados não dá para confiar nelas. Já falei isto em outra resposta minha (*link* no final). E não saberia dizer qual é mais confiável. Novamente, o termo é ruim.

## Campo

É o que guarda um estado do objeto. É uma das formas de se criar um atributo. É uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101). É uma porção de dados de um todo (um registro de um objeto). É um mecanismo concreto e existente nas implementações das linguagens e outras ferramentas.

Muitas vezes é chamado de variável membro. Vejo muito o uso até em casos onde ela é [imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) (veja [sobre constantes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203151/101) e [variáveis de somente leitura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151721/101)).

O termo variável não é conceitualmente o mesmo que campo, leia no *link* acima o que é uma variável. Em implementações mais esotéricas é possível um campo não ser uma variável. Na prática são.

O único termo aqui que é bem definido, todo mundo concorda, e em qualquer contexto (da nossa área) não é ambíguo.

Em POO ele é **sinônimo** de membro de dados. Que é diferente de ser intercambiável (duas coisas distintas que servem ao mesmo propósito).

[Smalltalk não usa o termo](http://www.objs.com/x3h7/smalltalk.htm) e prefere atributo. Se programar nesta linguagem seria melhor usar o termo dela. Mas quem programa em Smalltalk? Uma tecnologia que não tem sucesso pode ditar o que é correto quando outros dizem o oposto? Fica para o debate em outro lugar.

## Propriedade

É uma [forma mais concreta (mecanismo) de se definir um atributo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_(programming)) e uma forma geral de definir uma característica do objeto. É comum que uma propriedade tenha um ou mais campos relacionados para manter a característica armazenada. Mas é possível ter apenas um ou mais métodos (geralmente *getters* e *setters*) que forneçam estas características sem haver um estado intrínseco a ele.

Então sim, um método pode ser considerado um atributo de um objeto dependendo da forma como ele é definido. Ele faz algo que entrega uma característica do objeto.

Algumas linguagens proveem [sintaxe que unifica a ideia de campo e métodos acessador e mutador para a propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101), o que pode tornar seu consumo indistinto, como uma variável do objeto. Há quem considere só esta forma como propriedade.

Algumas pessoas consideram que a propriedade é(são) o(s) método(s) da característica e o campo algo distinto, e que o atributo seria a conjunção de ambos.

Mas há quem pense exatamente o oposto, ou seja, o atributo seria o campo, e a propriedade seria o conjunto, o que me parece muito errado, mas é meu ponto de vista.

Alguns consideram que propriedade é a forma pública da característica e o campo e métodos privados ligados a ele seriam o detalhe de implementação da característica. Portanto um campo público seria uma propriedade tanto quanto métodos públicos são. E um método privado jamais poderia ser uma propriedade. Faz algum sentido.

Algumas pessoas consideram que só é propriedade se permitir acessar e/ou mudar o estado, ainda que indiretamente (por cálculo, por exemplo). O que faria um campo público ser uma propriedade.

Em [vários campos do conhecimento a propriedade realmente é um sinônimo de atributo em muitos casos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_(philosophy)). O que, do ponto de vista técnico, faria o termo ser desnecessário. Curiosamente não vejo muito as pessoas intercambiando entre atributo e propriedade, ocorre mais entre atributo e campo.

Eu acho que o termo deveria ser reservado para o mecanismo (como define a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_(programming))), deixando ele menos ambíguo. Deixe o atributo para qualificar algo, seja na implementação (informação acessória de uma parte do objeto), seja conceitualmente (característica do objeto, sem detalhe de implementação).

Dependendo da linguagem podem usar o termo em um contexto específico ou de forma específica.

Ou seja, o termo é ruim exceto em um contexto específico, como o que o C# usa, por exemplo. E ajuda entender o [*link*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties/) colocado pelo utluiz na resposta dele.

## Variáveis

A pergunta não parecia se importar com isto, mas pela resposta do próprio AP, importa. Acho que isto já foi explicado em [Qual a diferença entre variáveis de instância de classe, automáticas (locais) e de duração estática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/257817/101).

## Conclusão

#### Atributos de classes

Note que estou falando do objeto, tudo isto se aplica à classe também. O que é diferente? O que se refere ao objeto é o que terá em cada instância modelada a partir da classe (ou protótipo), e o que se refere à classe em si só existe singularmente no código, não há instâncias, é algo que só faz sentido existir no modelo. Em outras palavras, é o que costuma-se chamar de estático.

#### Termo ruim

Como quase tudo que se fala em programação orientada a objeto, tem quem pense diferente e pode ser contestado, um dos motivos de eu não ser muito fã do paradigma, e por isso o uso de forma mais pragmática onde suas ideias básicas são úteis, nada de idealismo e purismo.

Pode ser uma interpretação de texto errada que se perpetuou, como ocorreu com vários outros ("`goto` é danoso", "otimização prematura é do mal", "Java roda em todas as plataformas", "todos devem aprender programação", e coisas assim).

#### Evidências

O fato de alguém escrever ele em um artigo não torna algo verdade. O fato de ter várias pessoas citando e copiando deste artigo também. Isto significa apenas que há quem pense desta maneira.

Por isso eu prefiro dizer que tem várias definições, escolha a sua, porque eu não posso provar que a minha definição é a certa.

As evidências só mostram que há controvérsias. Mas pra não ficar em cima do muro prefiro me basear no que parece mais fundamentado, mais sólido, mais coerente, mais intuitivo, ainda que isto seja subjetivo.

Ignoro principalmente artigos que são ambíguos. Temos que separar o que é artigo de divulgação e artigo de exposição de conhecimento.

#### OOP é difícil

Eu ainda estou aprendendo sobre OO, e estou fazendo isto nos últimos 30 anos, nos mais recentes tenho feito grande progresso e desmistificando coisas que eu aprendi errado, mudando de opinião.

Já que há controvérsias nas definições, crio minha própria definição baseada em fatos e axiomas já testados e menos em opiniões e interpretações com baixo fundamento.

Não tome esta como resposta definitiva e universal, o assunto é mais complicado do que parece e sem dominá-lo não dá para fazer certo.

#### Minha definição

- **Atributo** - define qualidade (característica) de alguma parte ou característica de um objeto (uma parte do código, por exemplo). É um metadado. Alguns fazem parte da especificação da linguagem, outros podem ser criados no seu código e usados.
- **Propriedade** - Característica que o objeto terá, uma informação que o definirá adjetivamente em um aspecto específico. No geral tendo a aceitar que não importa o mecanismo, mas tem linguagem que se refere a um mecanismo específico.
- **Campo** - Uma parte do objeto que guarda estado dele. Essencialmente é uma variável.

#### Sem formalismo

Como é muito comum usarem atributo como campo, e na maioria das vezes funciona, entenda que, na prática, quase sempre estão falando de um campo quando na verdade usam o termo de um conjunto de características de uma parte do objeto.

Mas ainda não dá para dizer que os termos dizem a mesma coisa. Seria o mesmo que dizer que [classe abstrata, interface, *trait* e *mixin* são a mesma coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/279252/101). na verdade estes conceitos estão mais relacionados que os termos da pergunta.

Me impressiona quando alguém contesta se o termo está sendo usado de forma correta e defende ambiguidade. Dê nome correto para cada coisa, não aceite sinônimos, a não ser na informalidade, mesmo assim evite. É ruim termos dois nomes para a mesma coisa e é ruim ter duas coisas com o mesmo nome.

#### Mais informações

Também é útil saber [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101).

Também pode querer saber o [Conceito de classe, entidade e objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203166/101).

Aceito contestações e sugestões e editarem para refleti-las.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O termo *elemento* também poderia ser utilizado em OOP? Ex: "elementos do objeto tal". Eu vejo que é bem comum em linguagens de marcação, mas, não sei se é comum em OOP.

Comment: Há quem use, eu não gosto. Acho que elemento remete mais a uma coleção de dados, como o *array*. Prefiro membro para um objeto. É a questão do conjunto ser homogêneo ou heterogêneo, poucos e definidos itens ou muitos e quantidade indefinida.

Comment: Atributo pode ser uma propriedade? Por isso as normas e padronizações é bom para discutir isso.

http://swebokwiki.org/Chapter_2:_Software_Design

Essa segunda vale a pena ter NBR ISO/IEC 12119;

Comment: Acho essa discussão legal, a melhor até agora sobre conceito.

Comment: @alxwca a ideia era essa, e ótimo link, vou dissecá-lo :)

Comment: Uma variável estática ou uma constante seria considerada ainda assim um campo?

Comment: @DanOver O meu entendimento é que sim, e nunca vi nada em contrário.

Answer (score 13):

### TL;DR

As outras respostas são interessantes em como elas destrincham os diferentes usos dos termos *atributo*, *campo* e *propriedade*. São úteis para reflexão. Em contextos, paradigmas ou tecnologias específicos realmente há diferenças entre eles.

***Entretanto, se, após ler respostas, artigos, e definições enciclopédicas, você ainda fica confuso, tome isto como uma forte evidência de que as diferenças são artificiais.***

Ao analisar tais termos de forma abrangente, a única conclusão possível é de que não existe uma terminologia definitiva.

O melhor, em minha opinião, é evitar distinções arbitrárias e artificiais, com exceção de tecnologias ou paradigmas específicos onde faça sentido.

Vou tentar demonstrar isto nos tópicos abaixo...

### Campo

Este termo provavelmente foi muito utilizado como uma analogia a formulários físicos. Quando você abre uma conta no banco ou passa a limpa o gabarito de uma prova, você está preenchendo os *campos* do formulários com seus respectivos valores.

Num sistema de informação, campos podem fazer referência aos elementos que definem uma tabela de banco de dados, aos diferentes espaços numa estrutura de dados alocada em memória ou ao espaço na tela que o usuário tem para entrar um dado específico.

Em ambos os casos, as pessoas comumente aplicam o termo tanto para referir-se à definição do campo quando ao campo em si num formulário contendo um valor específico.

Exemplos:

> Preencha o campo nome.
>   O valor do campo nome é "Maria".

O termo *campo* não combina com o paradigma de orientação a objetos.

### Atributo

Por vezes referido como *característica*, o termo faz todo sentido quando falamos de uma classe ou objeto. Em OO, uma classe possui membros, os quais comumente são divididos em atributos e métodos (características + comportamento).

O termo pode ser usado tanto para as definições de uma classe quando para o valor concreto de um objeto.

Exemplos:

> O atributo nome da classe cliente.
>   O atributo nome do cliente 1234 contém o valor "Maria".

### Propriedade

Em geral [não há distinção entre *propriedade*, *atributo*, *característica* ou *qualidade*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties/), a não ser que seja uma definição arbitrária ou específica.

Exemplos:

- HTML: tags possuem, cada uma, um conjunto de atributos e os valores desses atributos, quando definidos num elemento, são chamados de propriedades do elemento.
- JavaScript, como executado nos browsers atuais, sem definição de classes, *propriedades* se referem ao conjunto de atributos e seus respectivos valores em um objeto.
- Em muitos softwares, tal como editores visuais, quando você seleciona um objeto na tela, há um componente que permite editar as *propriedades* dele. O conjunto de propriedades geralmente varia conforme o tipo de objeto selecionado.
- Em Java, se tentássemos aplicar tal terminologia, poderíamos dizer que os atributos definidos numa classe serão sempre os mesmos que as propriedades de suas instâncias. Portanto referir-se aos *valores dos atributos* de uma instância é exatamente o mesmo que *valores das propriedades* da mesma.
- Numa linguagem mista, onde fosse possível definir propriedades estaticamente e também adicionar  outras propriedades dinamicamente, em tempo de execução, o conjunto de propriedades poderia ser diferente, um superconjunto, do conjunto de atributos.

O importante aqui é entender que as distinções são arbitrárias e não  parte da essência do termo *propriedade*.

### Paralelo com outros termos de programação

Esta discussão me lembra a questão [Quais são as definições de método, função e procedimento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11848/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-defini%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-m%C3%A9todo-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-procedimento)

Da mesma forma, ambos têm diferenças semânticas que variam conforme o contexto, mas na prática são a mesma coisa, seja referindo-se a um grupo de instruções (rotina, método, função) ou de um espaço de memória associado a uma estrutura (atributo, campo, propriedade).

### Paralelo com outras áreas

Quando falamos em *propriedades*, *qualidades*, *atributos* ou *características* de um elemento químico, nos referimos ao que é comum a todo o conjunto de matéria existente daquele elemento. Podemos ainda falar dos *propriedades*, *qualidades*, *atributos* ou *características* comuns a todos gatos domésticos.

Por outro lado, se falamos de um ente específico, tal como a cadeira que você senta para trabalhar ou o gato Félix, teremos então valores específicos para suas *propriedades*, *qualidades*, *atributos* ou *características*.

Está é uma analogia entre classe e objeto/instância.

### Conclusão

Com tudo isso, meu argumento é que não faz muito sentido fazer uma distinção forte entre *campo*, *propriedade* e *atributo*, forçando assim uma ginástica mental cada vez que somos confrontados com os termos.

Faz mais sentido traçar uma linha dividindo *definição* e *valor*. Fica muito mais simples fazer referência a um ou a outro assim:

- *Campo*

  - Definição: *o campo nome*
  - Valor: *o valor de nome* ou *o valor do campo nome*
- *Atributo*

  - Definição: *o atributo nome*
  - Valor: *o valor de nome* ou *o valor do atributo nome*
- *Propriedade*

  - Definição: *a propriedade nome*
  - Valor: *o valor de nome* ou *o valor da propriedade nome*

Dessa forma o sentido é claro usando qualquer um dos termos.

Answer (score 3):

Dependendo da linguagem de programação, não há distinção entre atributos, propriedades e campos. Normalmente sendo chamados sempre como campos ou atributos.

Normalmente chama-se de **propriedades** os campos que estão disponiveis através de metodos acessores (getters e setters). Mas como dito anteriormente, não há uma definição exata.

Comment: Não altera por linguagem, A modelagem é algo que faz parte de um processo, logo os processos são bem definidos. Em um diagrama de classe, atributos sempre serão atributos. Pois essa característica faz parte do processo de modelagem. Assim como as operações sempre serão operações e não métodos. Desde que faça parte do Processo de Modelagem. Geralmente pegamos dialetos de outras aéreas de construção de software e usamos como bem queremos e da nisso confusão.

Answer (score 2):

Na orientação a objetos temos o conceito de Atributos, que são as características que a classe pode ter. Ao analisar a literatura (livros, artigos, revistas científicas) não encontramos o conceito de campo ou propriedade relacionados a orientação a objetos. Sobre as propriedades, quando usamos java swing, vb.net, delphi ou alguma linguagem que permite a utilização de componentes, dizemos que estes componentes tem propriedades que podem ser modificadas para tingir determinado objetivo. Na prática, essa propriedades são atributos, Se pensarmos em campos, em banco de dados podemos dizer que temos colunas ou campos e se pegarmos um formulário em VB e Java Swing, podemos dizer que as caixas de textos são campos, que de fato, se programarmos corretamente no paradigma orientado a objetos, eles serão atributos de alguma classe. Para concluir, o correto é utilizar a nomenclatura de Atributo, já que uma classe é composta de atributos e métodos.

Answer (score 2):

A impressão que eu tenho é que no difundir da programação orientada a objetos diversos termos passaram a ser introduzidos na literatura e no cotidiano de quem atua na área de programação, alguns deles se tornaram ambíguos e outros trataram de tornar algo antes genérico ainda mais específico. Parte destes termos podem ter sido trazidos por aqueles que vieram de outras setores da TI, como por exemplo o termo "campo", pode ter sido adotado por profissionais com mais experiência em banco de dados. Mas, é tudo apenas uma suposição minha na tentativa de justificar a controvérsia.

> **Variáveis:**

- Variável é tudo aquilo que é declarado e capaz de armazenar valores em memória durante a execução de um programa. Pelo o que entendo, o termo "variável" não determina que para assim ser reconhecido o valor tenha que se modificar ao longo da execução da aplicação.
- Se forem declaradas fora de métodos e definitivas (constantes) ou estáticas, serão conhecidas como "**variáveis de classe**". Pois, estes dados são inerentes a classe e não a instância.
- Não sendo estáticas e nem constantes, porém ainda declaradas externamente aos métodos, são conhecidas como "**variáveis de instância**". Aqui os dados são inerentes a instância e não a classe como um todo.
- Declaradas internamente em métodos os serve enquanto estes estão sendo executados, neste caso são chamadas de "**variáveis locais**".
- Também se encaixam na definição de variáveis os parâmetros recebidos pelos métodos, chamados de "**variáveis de parâmetro**".
- Podem ser campos ou não campos, a distinção entre ambos pode ser compreendida abaixo.
- [Fonte](http://edayan.info/java/fields-vs-variables-in-java).

> **Atributo:**

- Segundo a [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atributo_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)), podemos definir como atributos as variáveis de **classe** e  **instância**.
- Também conhecido como **membro de classe**.

> **Campo:**

- Todos os campos são variáveis, porém nem toda variável é um campo.
- Membro de uma classe.
- Declarados fora dos métodos.
- Geralmente privado.
- Não possui getters ou setters.
- Utilizado normalmente de forma interna na classe.

> **Propriedade:**

- São campos expostos apenas através de métodos getters e setters.
- São campos privados que exigem um controle mais rigoroso quanto a sua leitura e escrita.

Comment: O artigo da Wikipedia em inglês, que eu e grande parte das pessoas sensatas consideram bem melhor, diz algo bem diferente do verbete em português, que é famosa por conter muitos erros e "donos" de verbetes que não deixam acertar. A primeira afirmação desta seção da resposta desmente a segunda, ou vice-versa.

Comment: Variáveis locais nada tem a ver com OOP, não sei o que isto faz aqui, talvez quisesse perguntar sobre isso, mas não está na pergunta. E por isso podemos dizer que todo campo é uma variável, a não ser que considere uma constante como campo, o que eu não sei definir ainda, e aí só poderia ser da classe, não pode ter constantes em instâncias. Um campo não pode ser membro de uma instância?  Como chama a mesma coisa que tem *getters e *setters*?

Comment: De acordo com a última seção, este campo seria propriedade? E como chama o(s) método(s) de *get/set*? E o conjunto deles? Poderia discorrer mais sobre o controle mais rigoroso que as propriedades devem ter? Não tem pressa, responde em comentário ou edite a resposta quando puder.

Comment: A primeira afirmação não desmente a segunda, apenas diz que uma variável não possui obrigação de "variar" para ser reconhecida como variável, ou seja, pode ser uma constante. A variação está na alocação em memória, que é feita de forma randômica, sem endereço fixo.

Comment: É que ela fala que são de classe ou instância, depois só fala em classe. Alocação da memória? Randômica? não entendi bem o que isto significa neste contexto.

Comment: Sim, durante a execução da aplicação, suas variáveis são temporariamente alocadas na RAM. A variável "x" recebe um endereço diferente (ou seja, variável) a cada nova execução da aplicação.

Comment: Isto não faz o menor sentido pra mim, mas deixe esse assunto pra lá porque ele não está na resposta, e nem tem a ver com a pergunta também, os outros pontos são mais importantes.

Comment: Tudo bem, minha resposta ficou ruim, eu concordo. Porém, ela reflete o que vejo por aí, basicamente campo, atributo e membro de classe, são tratados como sendo a mesma coisa. E talvez sejam. Já as variáveis, isso depende do paradigma do qual estamos falando. Na OOP, campo, atributo e membro de classe são também variáveis. O único detalhe que muda um pouco na definição são as chamadas "propriedades", que são campos privados acessados por métodos get/set.

Comment: Por isso que estou perguntando, quero que ela ajude todo mundo que está tendo dúvidas com isto, e achei que firam esses pontos que eu citei acima ainda como dúvida normal da maioria das pessoas.

Comment: Ao me ver se você tentar explicar sempre vai ter uma mistura de conceito da linguagem e do processo, Primeiro veio o paradigma Orientação a objeto, com  a necessidade de padronização as documentações, junto com isso UML, ouve uma mistura de conceito.

Comment: Bom para provar isso é pegar literatura antiga de Smaltalk, variáveis são variáveis e temos as pseudos variáveis. Mas Smaltalk não usa o paradigma orientado a objeto? Na analise,  Atributo de Classe é a qualidade da Classe?  Propriedade de minha classe não são atributos? Se tudo isso  tivesse sido  criado juntos seria mais fácil, UML 1994, Smaltalk 1969 e Simula.

Answer (score 0):

De uma forma geral, um objeto é capaz de carregar valores consigo, que definem seu estado, e os distingue dos demais objetos do mesmo tipo. Essa é a única definição que interessa.

Esses valores que os objetos podem carregar são referenciados de diversas formas na literatura: atributos, propriedades, campos, variáveis, argumentos, etc.

Algumas linguagens, inclusive, fornecem interpretações diferentes para cada um, no sentido de fornecer funcionalidades aos desenvolvedores e facilitar o uso, mas a finalidade sempre vai no encontro de permitir que o objeto carregue valores.

Na prática, discutir a diferença entre eles é tão produtivo quanto diferenciar funcionalmente métodos, de funções e procedimentos. Igual discutir que uma função que não retorna um valor não é uma função, ou que uma constante identificada não é uma variável.

Comment: Bom, eu acho fundamental e bem produtivo diferenciar métodos de funções, pois o conceito que as separam é trivial para qualquer profissional que queira saber o que está fazendo.

Comment: Não tenho a menor dúvida que separar conceitos tenha sua serventia, mas acho esse tipo de reflexão se encaixa em poucos lugares (é como comparar Java com Smalltalk para dizer que Java não é orientado a objetos).  Métodos são diferentes de funções conceitualmente, mas ambos continuam sendo um bloco de código que queremos reutilizar por algum motivo.  É difícil imaginar uma situação em que intercambiar os termos possa levar a um erro grave de entendimento.  O mesmo vale para atributos vs. campos.

Answer (score -5):

Em programação orientada a objetos, o termo "atributo" e "campo" são usados para se referir às variáveis que compõem a estrutura de uma classe. A principal diferença entre os dois é que os atributos podem incluir métodos de acesso e modificação (como getters e setters), enquanto os campos são simplesmente variáveis. Portanto, os atributos são geralmente considerados uma forma de encapsulamento de dados, enquanto os campos são simplesmente um pedaço da estrutura da classe.

Em algumas linguagens de programação, o termo "propriedade" é usado para se referir a atributos que incluem métodos de acesso e modificação. No entanto, essa não é uma definição universalmente aceita, e o uso do termo "propriedade" pode variar de uma linguagem para outra.

**Edit:**
*Favor desconsiderar resposta acima.*

Texto gerado com AI (ChatGpt) afim de testar confiabilidade do serviço como ferramenta de estudo.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: O texto foi gerado com AI (ChatGpt) afim de testar confiabilidade do serviço como ferramenta de estudo.